# Hide column if any value is null or zero via proc sql or view

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

Given either of the two following datasets

```
Kağıt Cinsi        Sarı      Yeşil      Mavi

Kalın                4         0          5
İnce               null        0          3
```

or

```
Kağıt Cinsi        Sarı      Yeşil      Mavi

Kalın                4         0          5
İnce                 0         0          3
```

I want to filter via either a stored procedure or a custom view to hide any column which contains a row with either a 'null' or 'zero' value.

These are the results: I would expect from either of the above datasets

```
Kağıt Cinsi       Mavi

Kalın               5
İnce                3
```

I'm not sure what a query for this looks like, but I want to return it from the database like this.

Comment: Do you now mean "hide column if all values are null or zero". or "hide column if any value is null or zero"?

Comment: @gbn -hide column if any value is null or zero.

Comment: So for row "İnce", Sarı is zero, why is it in the output?

Comment: Closing as off-topic because this is a programming/presentation issue (as indicated by the accepted answer) and not a database issue. The question would also likely be closed or migrated on [so] as is. Since it has an answer, I'm letting it lie, but future readers please know that I will have cleaned up the question to make it a little more digestable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should **NOT** be done inside the database.  There are several levels to any application:

- Data Layer (where the data is stored and retrieved from)
- ...
- Presentation Layer (where the data is displayed/visualised/presented)

As a good rule, the data layer should not dynamically exclude certain columns based on their values (rows yes, columns no).  This is the responsibility of the Presentation Layer to hide/display a column based on an arbitrary value.

Depending on what you're using as your presentation layer (C#, Excel, php, etc...) I would ask this question on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 3):

You can't hide a column dynamically unless you use dynamic SQL. This quickly gets complicated: what if the zeros are in different columns on different rows? What should the output be

If the zeros/nulls are in the same column, then you can "hide" a column by not selecting it.

```
SELECT 
   Kağıt Cinsi, Sarı, Mavi
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   (Yeşil IS NULL OR Yeşil = 0)
```

You may not need the filter here: I added it because the question was unclear

Comment: @gbn- As you mentioned,If the zeros/nulls are in different columns on different rows,I want to hide the column.I've updated my question.

Comment: @Cell-o: well, you need dynamic SQL to query a column to decide whether to add it to the output. Good luck