# SELECT column for a row only if its value is not empty

Tags: sqlite

I want to display a certain column only if its value is not empty.

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT column1, IF_NOT_EMPTY(column2), ... FROM table;
```

Will display all columns except column2 if column2 is empty.

Comment: Have you seen the ifnull function? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull. That may be of some use to you. However it sounds like you want to omit the entire column if a row value is empty... what happens if one row is empty but another is not for a particular column?

Comment: Yes I have seen it and yes I want it to be omitted. If not for a multirow result set then for a one row query.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a way to do that with standard sql you could use case to change that blank to a value https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-case-statement/

The consensus here was that this shouldn't be done on the DB side rather, in whatever mechanism is presenting the data:  [Hide column if any value is null or zero via proc sql or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6484/hide-column-if-any-value-is-null-or-zero-via-proc-sql-or-view)